# Extract embed font in CSS to TTF file?

Tags: css, fonts, truetype

i see this data from CSS file

src: url(data:font/truetype;....data here...);

can i extract this data and convert it to ttf file?

Comment: Very similar to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6920832/how-to-decode-base64-encoded-font-information

Answer (score 1):

http://www.motobit.com/util/base64-decoder-encoder.asp

using this online tool to decode the base64 string to a binary file :D