# Decode base64-encoded string to font file - unicode range

Tags: css, unicode, fonts, base64, font-face

I noticed recently that the method explained by Andrew Moore here isn't working anymore:

[How to decode base64-encoded font information?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6920832/how-to-decode-base64-encoded-font-information)

What I want to do is decode the base64-encoded string to a .bin file, then convert that .bin to .otf/.ttf.

I was able to do that successfully by follwoing Mr. Moore's example, but something changed in the encription (maybe) and I would like some help.

```
@font-face {
  font-family: "Family";
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: normal;
  src: url("data:font/opentype;base64,T1RUTwAN....AHMAdgB0");
  unicode-range: U+0-10FFFF;
}
```

I believe the addition of "unicode-range" in the CSS may have something to do with it. Can someone please help me decode these files again? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I answered this question on https://stackoverflow.com/a/37223719/101290

Here is the details:

Convert base64 fonts to other formats using the following steps:

1. Copy the base64 data.

   In `CSS` it's the part marked "THIS_CODE":

   ```
   @font-face {
     font-family:"font-name-here";
     src:url(data:font/opentype;base64,THIS_CODE);
   }
   ```
2. Decode the base64 data using a converter. Here are two online converters: [opinionatedgeek.com](http://www.opinionatedgeek.com/DotNet/Tools/Base64Decode/) and [motobit.com](http://www.motobit.com/util/base64-decoder-encoder.asp)

   These will both output a `.bin` file.
3. Go to [onlinefontconverter.com](https://onlinefontconverter.com) check the types of fonts that you want (maybe `OTF` or `TTF`) and then click "Select Font(s)" and upload the `.bin` file. Click "Done" and the site will find the desired font file formats, then offer you a link to download a zip file containing your desired font files.